# Execute tests using appium, selenium grid from serenity.properties

Tags: selenium, appium, selenium-grid, serenity-bdd

I need to run tests with selenium grid, appium and serenity with the settings in serenity.properties.

I run first using a driver class and the url of the local selenium grid and it works, but when I set the properties from the serenity.properties it doesn't run

clase Driver.java driver.java class **executes successfully**

```
public class Driver {
    public static WebDriver appiumDriver() {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities1 = new DesiredCapabilities();

         capabilities1.setCapability("platformVersion", "9");
         // capabilities1.setCapability("browserName", "Android");
         capabilities1.setCapability("platformName", "ANDROID");
         capabilities1.setCapability("udid", "341912d");
            capabilities1.setCapability("deviceName","Mi A2");
            capabilities1.setCapability("appPackage", "com.google.android.calculator");
         capabilities1.setCapability("appActivity","com.android.calculator2.Calculator");

         WebDriver driver1 = null;
         try {
            // driver1 = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities1);
             // driver1 = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities1);
            // driver1 = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities1);
            driver1 = new AppiumDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities1);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         return driver1;
    }
}
```

since serenity.properties **doesn't run**

```
webdriver.driver= appium
appium.hub = http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
appium.platformName=Android
appium.deviceName=Mi A2
appium.udid=341912d
appium.platformVersion=9.0
appium.appPackage=com.google.android.calculator
appium.appActivity=com.android.calculator2.Calculator
appium.app=
appium.browserName=appium
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the version of selenium grid